# AWS S3 has to load before I execute anything on the command line

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a django project integrated with s3, and everytime I want to execute something on the command line, e.g. `python manage.py migrate`, the terminal has to load this first:

```
BEGIN REQUEST++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Request URL = https://ec2.amazonaws.com?Action=DescribeRegions&Version=2013-10-15

RESPONSE++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Response code: 200

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DescribeRegionsResponse xmlns="http://ec2.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-10-15/">
    <requestId>936a670c-3q31-33kc-8713-1d0gbe6ad222</requestId>
    <regionInfo>
        <item>
            <regionName>ap-south-1</regionName>
            <regionEndpoint>ec2.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com</regionEndpoint>
        </item>
        <item>
            <regionName>eu-west-3</regionName>
            <regionEndpoint>ec2.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com</regionEndpoint>
        </item>
        <item>
            <regionName>eu-west-2</regionName>
            <regionEndpoint>ec2.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com</regionEndpoint>
        </item>
        <item>
            <regionName>eu-west-1</regionName>
            <regionEndpoint>ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com</regionEndpoint>
        </item>
        <item>
            <regionName>ap-northeast-2</regionName>
            <regionEndpoint>ec2.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com</regionEndpoint>
        </item>
        <item>
            <regionName>ap-northeast-1</regionName>
            <regionEndpoint>ec2.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com</regionEndpoint>
        </item>
        <item>
            <regionName>sa-east-1</regionName>
            <regionEndpoint>ec2.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com</regionEndpoint>
        </item>
        <item>
            <regionName>ca-central-1</regionName>
            <regionEndpoint>ec2.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com</regionEndpoint>
        </item>
        <item>
            <regionName>ap-southeast-1</regionName>
            <regionEndpoint>ec2.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com</regionEndpoint>
        </item>
        <item>
            <regionName>ap-southeast-2</regionName>
            <regionEndpoint>ec2.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com</regionEndpoint>
        </item>
        <item>
            <regionName>eu-central-1</regionName>
            <regionEndpoint>ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com</regionEndpoint>
        </item>
        <item>
            <regionName>us-east-1</regionName>
            <regionEndpoint>ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com</regionEndpoint>
        </item>
        <item>
            <regionName>us-east-2</regionName>
            <regionEndpoint>ec2.us-east-2.amazonaws.com</regionEndpoint>
        </item>
        <item>
            <regionName>us-west-1</regionName>
            <regionEndpoint>ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com</regionEndpoint>
        </item>
        <item>
            <regionName>us-west-2</regionName>
            <regionEndpoint>ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com</regionEndpoint>
        </item>
    </regionInfo>
</DescribeRegionsResponse>
```

and this creates a few seconds delay for my command to execute. Is there any way I can prevent this from happening as it's causing delays in development.

**settings.py**

```
from draft1.aws.conf import *
from draft1.aws.conf import S3_URL, AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
STATIC_URL = S3_URL + 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_URL
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'
```

Comment: It's nearly impossible to tell why this is happening without some code context? What packages do you have installed? Are you using virtualenv? You could start by grepping your project (and venv dir) for `BEGIN REQUEST++++++`

Comment: I've added my s3 segment from my settings.py, could that be it?

Comment: Sounds likely. Again, try grepping. See where that gets printed. Then throw `raise Exception('let\'s find out where this is coming from')` before it and you'll get a stacktrace that should show you what's causing that to be run.

Comment: Grep your project for `boto` or `boto3` if you're using AWS python sdk. Move the contents of the `~/.aws` folder to some other folder or temporarily remove the aws credentials from your project (if it's your local development environment) which will make the function call to raise an exception. You can then post the stack trace here